# Matlab: Abort function call with Strg+C but KEEP return value

Tags: function, matlab, return-value, terminate

I have a function in matlab with something like this:

```
function [ out ] = myFunc(arg1, arg2)
    times = [];
    for i = 1:arg1
        tic
        % do some long calculations
        times = [times; toc];
    end

    % Return
    out = times;
end
```

I want to abort the running function now but keep the values of `times` which are currently already taken. How to do it? When I press strg+c, I simply loose it because it's only a local function variable which is deleted when the function leaves the scope...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to turn it from a function to a script, where times would no longer be a local variable.

The more elegant solution would be to save the times variable to a .mat file within the loop. Depending on the time per iteration, you could do this on every loop, or once every ten loops, etc.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. The thing is: It's also as above running since 24hours and I want to abort it for now but keep the values ... is there a way?

Comment: I can't think of one - I'm sorry. One other thing, though - if you type in "dbstop if error" then pressing Control-C would allow you to look at the internal values too. Next time, I guess.

Comment: Argh damn it :( But okay, thanks than for this tipp I'll take this into account but probably just rewrite my algorithm a bit to save all variables to a mat-file.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use [persistent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html) variables to solve your problem, e.g.

```
function [ out ] = myFunc(arg1, arg2)
    persistent times
    if nargin == 0
        out = times;
        return;
    end;
    times = [];
    for i = 1:arg1
        tic
        % do some long calculations
        times = [times; toc];
    end

    % Return
    out = times;
end
```

I'm not sure whether persistent variables are cleared upon Ctrl-C, but I don't think it should be the case. What this should do: if you supply arguments, it will run as before. When you omit all arguments however, the last value of times should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

`onCleanup` functions still fire in the presence of CTRL-C, however I don't think that's really going to help because it will be hard for you to connect the value you want to the `onCleanup` function handle (there are some tricky variable lifetime issues here). You may have more luck using a MATLAB handle object to track your value. For example

```
x = containers.Map(); x('Value') = [];
myFcn(x); % updates x('Value') 
% CTRL-C
x('Value') % contains latest value
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the `assignin` function to send the data to your workspace on each iteration. e.g.

```
function [ out ] = myFunc(arg1, arg2)
    times = [];
    for i = 1:arg1
        tic
        % do some long calculations
        times = [times; toc];
        % copy the variable to the base workspace
        assignin('base', 'thelasttimes', times)
    end

    % Return
    out = times;
end
```